# What will happen if I repot my Acers in May

Tags: repotting, maple

Good afternoon. I wonder if you would answer a question that is if real concern to me.
I can see that the common advice for  reporting acers is to do this in April or September. Due to this lack of deliveries I have only now been able to get 2xlarger pots and the appropriate John Innes 3 delivering this week. 
I have attached two photos of the Acer trees and wanted to know what will happen if I was hoping to repot them when the larger pots arrive at the end of next week ?
I would be most grateful if you would let me know

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about the timing. I've worked for several plant nurseries that sold and installed trees and shrubs, and we would repot or plant throughout the growing season except during late July/early August (the hottest part of our summer) or during a drought. What is most important is that you give the trees adequate water after you've repotted them. You could also consider mulching the tops of the pots with something organic to help keep the moisture levels up, and maybe some fertilizer (but no fertilizer after August 1st or so - you don't want lots of new growth going into winter).

Answer (score 1):

It'll be fine - it will only be a day or so into May, and all you're doing is moving them into larger pots, not planting them in open ground. Water in well once it's done.